# Shell script Program accessing DB directory folder when running from oracle applications

Tags: shell, unix

The program should go to **DB directory** folder **/u01/app/oracle/admin/ibmcp1/inbound/**
and write a file **OUTBOUND.txt** with file names of **IBM.SOURCE.INVE.xml**.

But the log file says as shown below: I m running this shell script.prog from oracle application concurrernt manager which is on application server
and it is trying search the DB directory, but this DB directory is in DB node.

could you let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
===========================
#!/bin/ksh
p_login_info=`echo $1`
PATH_PREFIX=/u01/app/oracle/admin/
PATH_SUFIX=/cfs_ipp_interface/file_repository/inbound/
FILE_PREFIX=IBM.SOURCE.INVE
table="v\$instance"
echo "Change Directory"
INSTANCE=`sqlplus -s $p_login_info <<-EOSQL1
set heading off
SELECT instance_name FROM $table;
EXIT;
/
EOSQL1`
echo "Instance="$INSTANCE
INSTANCE=$(echo $INSTANCE |sed 's/ no/no/g' )
FILE_PATH=$PATH_PREFIX$INSTANCE$PATH_SUFIX
echo "File Path= "$FILE_PATH
cd $FILE_PATH
LOGFILE=$FILE_PATH/OUTPUT.txt 
>$LOGFILE

 for i in ` ls ${FILE_PREFIX}* `
 do
   FILE=`basename $i`
         echo $FILE >> $LOGFILE
 done

 echo "Processing Completed"
```

================================================
**lOG FILE:**

```
Change Directory
Instance= ibmcp1
File Path= /u01/app/oracle/admin/ibmcp1/inbound/
/apps/ibmgr12/apps/apps_st/appl/xxibm/12.0.0/bin/xxibm_file_names.prog[19]: cd: /u01/app/oracle/admin/ibmcp1/inbound/: [No such file or directory]
/apps/ibmgr12/apps/apps_st/appl/xxibm/12.0.0/bin/xxibm_file_names.prog.prog[21]: /u01/app/oracle/admin/ibmcp1/inbound//OUTBOUND.txt: cannot create [No such file or directory]
ls: cannot access IBM.SOURCE.INVE*: No such file or directory
Processing Completed
```

Thanks

Comment: small note: you should not ``p_login_info=`echo $1` ``, the echo is unnecessary. just do `p_login_info=$1`

Comment: Your main error is  missing `mkdir -p "$FILE_PATH"`

Comment: Please read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: For _lots_ more feedback, paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net